Law of Large Numbers for Changing Distributions
I thought of the following problem:

Suppose there is a school with 1000 students. A random sample of 50
students is selected and each of these 50 students is asked to run 100
meters and the time is recorded for each of these 50 students. We are
interested in knowing how the properties of this sample (e.g. average
speed, standard deviation of speed) generalize to the same properties
at the population level.

As I understand, traditional statistics (i.e. Frequentist) would use mathematical theorems like Central Limit Theorem (CLT) and the Law of Large Numbers (LLN) to analyze such situations. LLN states that the as the sample size increases, the sample average becomes closer and closer to the population average. On the other hand, CLT states that the distribution of the sample averages approaches a (Standard) Normal Distribution when multiple sample averages are analyzed.
But at the same time, in traditional statistics believes that the population level parameters (i.e. population mean, population standard deviation) are fixed, deterministic and non-random quantities. Traditional statistics believes that randomness is only contained in the sample that you observe from the population. For example, if another sample of 50 students were chosen - perhaps the sample average of these students would be different from the first sample due to randomness. But as the sample size increases, the effect of this randomness becomes negligible and the sample averages become closer to the population average - and the population average is a fixed quantity.
My Question: What if now we believe that the population level parameters are also random quantities - will classical theorems like CLT and LLN still apply? For example, if the population of all 1000 students were to run 100 meters today and their average time was recorded  ... and the same population of 1000 students were to run 100 meters tomorrow and their average time was recorded .... even though these are population level parameters ... they can still be subject to randomness (i.e. The distribution is "moving"). This means that there is no "single" population level parameter and it is inherently varying  . From a philosophical level, this means that there is no "single, true population" - and the population inherently exists as a spectrum of infinite versions of this populations, in which even if the observation conditions are attempted to be made fixed, there will still be variability in the population.... and we are destined to only observe a single version of this population.
To make this question a bit more mathematical, consider a random variable $X$ such that:
Level 1: $$ X \sim N(\mu, \sigma)$$
Level 2:
$$ \mu \sim N(\theta_1, \theta_2)$$
$$ \sigma \sim N(\theta_3, \theta_4)$$
Next, consider the following situation ($\theta_1$, $\theta_2$,$\theta_3$, $\theta_4$ are fixed values) :

Situation A:

Step 1: A single set of $\mu, \sigma $ is randomly generated according to their probability distributions.
Step 2: From there, we randomly generate 50 values of $X$ using the $\mu, \sigma$ from Step 1 . END


Situation B:

Step 1: A set of of $\mu, \sigma$ is randomly generated according to their probability distributions.
Step 2: A single value of X is generated using the $\mu, \sigma$ from Step 1.
Step 3: Step 1 and Step 2 are now repeated 50 times. END



Now, suppose we are given $X_A =  x_1, x_2, ... x_{50}$ and $X_B =  x_1, x_2, ... x_{50}$.
Assume we are unaware of the existence of Level 2 and we only believe that $X =  x_1, x_2, ... x_50$ came from Level 1. We are interested in estimating the properties of the population level parameters.
For both of these Situations : Will CLT and LLN apply?
My guess is no - since both CLT and LLN require finite variance?
Note 1: I tried to draw a picture to represent this situation:

It seems to me that the concept of estimation is predicated on the fact that variation across a single population needs to be much greater than variation across all possible populations.

If this is the case, then the fact that we could have observed an infinite number of populations does not have significant impact on our problem.

If this is the case, then the fact that we could have observed an infinite number of populations does have significant impact on our problem. This means that we are effectively comparing apples to oranges.


Note 2: Related Question: A Normal Distribution of Normal Distributions

Your estimation of $\sigma$ as written will be ill-posed since it can be positive or negative and only $\sigma^2$ can be estimated. It is more common to model $\sigma^2$ with an inverse gamma distribution or some other distribution defined on $(0,\infty)$. The tail behavior of this distribution will have a large impact on the variance of $X$ so I suspect it will be important in the analysis

@ whpowell96 : thank you so much for your reply! If you have time, can you please post an answer about this?

In statistics, this is well-known setup and would be an example of a multilevel model.
This means that there is not a single population, but rather a set of populations with hierarchical structure. Typically, we would assume that the distribution of run times of a student $i$ are distributed according to some location-scale family of distributions $F$ (like the normal distribution):
$$
X_i \sim F(\mu_i, \sigma_i)
$$
I.e. in frequentist term, we assume there is a population of possible runs each student could do.
We then assume that those location and scale parameters across students are drawn from some other distribution. I.e. in frequentist terms, there is a population of students:
$$
\mu_i \sim F_{\mu}(\alpha, \tau) \\
\sigma_i \sim F_{\sigma}(\beta, \rho)
$$
Where $F_{\mu}, F_{\sigma}$ are also location-scale families, with $F_{\sigma}$ constrained to $[0, \infty)$. For example, we could have $F_{\mu}$ normal and $F_{\sigma}$ lognormal.
It is common to assume that the variance is identical ($\forall i: \sigma_i = \sigma$) as this simplifies a lot of things, but it is not necessary.
Now, something like CLT/LLN usually holds, but note that we now don't have a single central limit theorem, but instead multiple different CLTs, because there is no longer a single "size of the dataset". Let's denote $N$ the number of students and $K_i$ the number of runs of student $i$ we observe, assume $F, F_{\mu}, F_{\sigma}$ are well-behaved (I think finite second moments should be enough, but you likely actually need less) and walk through some important cases:

$N \to \infty, \ K_i \to \infty$. CLT holds for all parameters.

$N$ constant, $K_i \to \infty$. CLT holds for $\mu_i, \sigma_i$ but not for $\alpha, \beta, \tau, \rho$

$N \to \infty, K_i = 1$. CLT holds for $\alpha$, and not for $\mu_i, \sigma_i$. The behaviour for other parameters will depend on the specific distribution families, but for many cases (e.g. $F, F_{\mu}$ normal) you cannot distinguish the within-student variance ($\sigma_i$) from the between-student varaince ($\tau$) and thus CLT will hold only for some function of the parameters, but not for the parameters themselves (e.g. assuming normal distributions and $\sigma_i = \sigma$ constant, CLT will hold for $\nu^2 = \sigma^2 + \tau^2$)

$N \to \infty, K_i > 1$ constant. CLT holds for $\alpha, \tau, \beta, \rho$ but not for $\mu_i, \sigma_i$.



Random remarks:

Statistics questions probably get better answers on https://stats.stackexchange.com

In general, you can put probability distributions on your parameters: that's called Bayesian inference. It's a non-orthodox framework for statistical inference. Note that a lot of ink has been spilled onto the respective merits and shortfalls of the various statistical frameworks.

In you particular case, I don't think that's necessary. You can think of the random variable: "what is the average running time of all students today" but you can also think of the parameter: "what is the average running time of all students, also averaging over all running conditions". That parameter could be treated in a frequentist or bayesian paradigm.

Once we start thinking about how the conditions of the day can impact the results of the experiment, we are in statistical trouble since that implies that the "average running time of 50 students today" cannot tell us about the performance in other days.

The CLT can still be applied in two-step processes by conditioning on the result of the first step.

The CLT does not require finite variance, even though it helps, both in stating and proving the theorem. This has been known since the earliest full derivations by Levy and Lindeberg, even though it is extremely rarely cited in this form. See this delightful review of the history of the CLT by Le Cam for more information http://users.math.uoc.gr/~frantzikinakis/Probability2013/CLTaround1935.pdf



@ Guillaume Dehaene: thank you so much for your answer! Can you please expand on 5)?

Taking a famous example about crab biology assume that the size of a crab depends on its sex (bernoulli 0.5) and then the additive sum of a large number of small variables. Conditional on sex, the size of a crab is almost Gaussian (CLT), but the marginal distribution of the sizes is a mixture of two gaussians. In humans, I believe the difference between the sexes is small enough that the marginal is still quasi-gaussian, but for these crabs the marginal distribution is far from gaussian. (environment also has a major influence)
